# How to link C++ Standard Library to Monotouch application

Tags: c++, binding, xamarin.ios, standard-library

I am binding an enterprise library to my Monotouch application.
It has been an arduous process since Objective Sharpie failed to create the APIs and I had to get creative.
But now, after the compilation finally succeeded I'm faced with a linking problem

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initIPcEENS_9enable_ifIXsr21__is_forward_iteratorIT_EE5valueEvE4typeES9_S9_ in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::resize(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::str(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::push_back(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int)in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      wflang::CWfStringBody::Float64ToArray(double, unsigned short*)in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      virtual thunk to std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf()in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf()in libWeANDSFLibrary.a(WfStringBody.o)
      ...
```

Etc.
I tried following the advice in [Wrapping a C++ library in Objective-C is not hiding the C++ symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312267/wrapping-a-c-library-in-objective-c-is-not-hiding-the-c-symbols) but it didn't work.
Any idea?

Comment: It would be best if you post the entire solution, without it, I suspect you are missing references to libraries, or you have ForceLoad instead of SmartLink.   Or other C++ bits that go into the LinkWith attribute

Comment: Using SmarkLink solved that problem but now I'm getting 'Could not create an native instance of the type 'WeFiApi.WeANDSFClient': the native class hasn't been loaded.
It is possible to ignore this condition by setting MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.' Is that related?

Comment: Miguel, where can I post the solution with limited accessibility? I can't post it publicly since it's a client's IP.

Comment: @shy bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what finally solved the problem was linking the standard C++ library using

> LinkerFlags="-lsqlite3.0 -lc++"

My entire LinkWith attribute looks like this:

> [assembly: LinkWith ("libMyLibrary.a", LinkTarget = LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, SmartLink = true, ForceLoad = true, IsCxx = true, Frameworks = "SystemConfiguration CoreLocation CoreTelephony MobileCoreServices MessageUI", LinkerFlags="-lsqlite3.0 -lc++")]

Answer (score 4):

Hello it seems you are compiling using a non c++ compiler, you might want to try setting it inside your **iOS project options** or inside the `LinkWith attribute` you should set `IsCxx = true` on your **iOS binding Project**

available options on **iOS project build options** are

- --compiler:gcc
- --compiler:g++
- --compiler:clang
- --compiler:clang++

you should try either `--compiler:g++` or `--compiler:clang++`

[image]

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for you answer but I'm afraid it didn't work.